# Enviar objeto do AngularJs para POST da API C#

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

Não estou conseguindo salvar os dados cadastrados em um form no banco de dados SQL Server.

A estrutura está a seguinte:

A classe:

```
public partial class EMPRESAS_PARTICIPANTES
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public int ID_AUX { get; set; }

    [StringLength(150)]
    public string NOME_FANTASIA { get; set; }

    [StringLength(20)]
    public string CNPJ_CPF { get; set; }

    [StringLength(20)]
    public string TELEFONE_01 { get; set; }

    [StringLength(20)]
    public string CELULAR { get; set; }

    [StringLength(100)]
    public string EMAIL { get; set; }
}
```

Tenho um form:

```
<form name="novoCrmForm">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group text-left col-md-8">
            <label for="Nome">Nome <i class="danger">*</i></label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="empresaParticipante.nomE_FANTASIA" name="nomE_FANTASIA" placeholder="Nome" ng-required="true" ng-minlength="2" ng-maxlength="150">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group text-left col-md-4">
            <label for="cpf">CPF</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="empresaParticipante.cnpJ_CPF" name="cnpJ_CPF" placeholder="CPF" ng-required="true">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group text-left col-md-6">
            <label for="Celular">Celular <i class="danger">*</i></label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="empresaParticipante.celular" name="celular" placeholder="Celular">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group text-left col-md-6">
            <label for="Telefone">Telefone</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="empresaParticipante.telefonE_01" name="telefonE_01" placeholder="Telefone">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group text-left col-md-12">
            <label for="Email">Email <i class="danger">*</i></label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" ng-model="empresaParticipante.email" name="email" placeholder="Email" ng-required="true" ng-minlength="2" ng-maxlength="50">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-dismiss="modal" ng-click="adicionarRegistro(empresaParticipante)" ng-disabled="novoCrmForm.$invalid">Salvar</button>
```

e a partir do salvar, envia para um function do AngularJs:

```
var adicionarRegistro = function (empresaParticipante) {
    empresaParticipante.data = new Date();
    $http.post("http://localhost:50183/api/crm/salvar", empresaParticipante).success(function (data) {
        delete $scope.empresaParticipante;
        $scope.novoCrmForm.$setPristine();
        carregarRegistros();
    });
};
```

Nesta function do AngularJs, envia o objeto para a API em C#.
O problema é que já ao receber o parâmetro, na assinatura do método, o mesmo chega vazio.

```
[Route("salvar")]
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage post([FromBody] EMPRESAS_PARTICIPANTES empresaParticipante)
{
    IEmpresas_ParticipantesBO Empresas_ParticipantesBO = new Empresas_ParticipantesBO();
    Retorno retorno = new Retorno();

    try
    {
        //salvar
        retorno = Empresas_ParticipantesBO.salvar(empresaParticipante);
    ...
    } 
    catch(Exception){}
}
```

Alguém sabe o motivo do objeto estar chegando na API vazio? Como posso resolver?

---

Obs.:

- Estou utilizando apenas alguns campos da tabela,
- A tabela não tem campos obrigatórios,
- A classe foi mapeada com CodeFirst.

Comment: Você já tentou verificar se o objeto não está sendo enviado vazio? Ex.: Dar um `console.log(objeto)` antes de enviar para API é uma boa ideia.

Comment: jbueno também fiz isso, e no console não aparece o objeto.

Comment: Tá, então o problema tá no lado cliente. Então a função `adicionarRegistro` não recebe nada ao clicar em salvar, certo?

Comment: certo, isso mesmo que esta acontecendo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui fazer o button que esta no for chamar a function do AngularJs.

Apesar não entender direito o motivo. Ainda!

a Solução foi a seguinte:

Quando inicia a App do Angular, eu joguei para uma variável, e ao instanciar o controller, eu não declarei o `angular.module("Crm" []);` novamente, mas somente instanciei o controller na variável que já tinha declarada minha app.

segue exemplo abaixo:

```
var crmApp = angular.module("Crm", []);
crmApp.controller("CrmCtrl", function ($scope, $http) {
```

Após este atribuição, o meu form esta chamando a function do Angular.

Answer (score 0):

Você possui a classe EMPRESAS_PARTICIPANTES?

Veja um exemplo que eu fiz:

```
 public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]RRNC plano)
        {
            try
            {
                rnc.Salvar(plano);

                this.texto = new HttpError(mensagem.PostWeb());
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, texto);

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                this.texto = new HttpError(mensagem.ErroWeb());
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, texto);
            }

        }
```

Angular:

```
recursoRNC.salvar($scope.rnc, function (retorno) {
                    notificacao.informacao(retorno.Message);
                    $scope.buscarTodos();
                }, function (erro) {
                    notificacao.alerta(erro.data.Message);
                });
```

No angular, empresaParticipante, possui o mesmo nome de campo que no EMPRESAS_PARTICIPANTES do WebAPI?

Comment: Jovem, como é que ele ia compilar o projeto sem ter essa classe? Essa resposta merece um negativo...

Comment: Realmente deu uma bola fora kkkkk Posta a sua classe EMPRESAS_PARTICIPANTES BSilva

Comment: Desculpem, postei a classe.